# Javascript closures (I think)

Tags: javascript, closures

I've got a piece of code I'm working with that was handed down to me by a previous developer. I am just trying to understand it better and not just use it naively.  Here's the code:

```
slides.paginator.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    interval.stop();
    switchSlide($(this).index());
    interval.start();
});
```

The part that I do not understand is the argument `e` that is being passed through this anonymous function. I have seen this before and I thought it had something to do with closures, but again, I am not sure. Can anyone give me a little insight into exactly how this parameter `e` works? I have seen it in other cases as well, such as with jQuery's AJAX methods.

Even pointing me in the right direction towards an article would be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: This is the click event itself

Comment: A very general explanation (ignoring the fact that this is an event handler): You pass a function into the `slides.paginator.click` function. The `slides.paginator.click` will call your function when a click occurs. The `e` is simply parameter in the function that you pass in, and `slides.paginator.click` will supply the appropriate argument later.

Comment: I see. Well I guess my next question is how do I know that the click handler will provide such an event? (As I'm writing this comment, I realize I might have just answered my own question. But I would like to make sure from you guys first =] )

Comment: The click handler is the anonymous function. The event is passed to that function.

Comment: *"...how do I know that the click handler will provide such an event"*. By reading API documentation.

Comment: In the [`.click()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/), you'll see: `.click( handler(eventObject) )` This is a description of the signature of the `.click()` method. It shows that it expects to receive a function to which an *eventObject* will be passed when invoked.

Comment: Here’s a link to the docs where jQuery explains all of it’s event object properties: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: @FillipPeyton: If all you wanted to know was the capabilities of the *value* passed to the `e` parameter in this instance, then you should have asked about that. You're question suggests you want to know how the callback gets its argument, and if it had something to do with closures.

Comment: @the system: And I would have, if I had realized that the jquery `.click()` method returned this `eventObject`. I thought there might have been something I was missing that had nothing to do with the method, and everything to do with the anonymous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"e" comes from "event", check the jquery .click() docs http://api.jquery.com/click/

function(e){} replaces "handler(eventObject)"

Comment: I see. Well, how do I know what is being passed in that eventObject that I can reference? I notice `e.preventDefault();` is being called, which I know stops the default behavior from happening. Now that I think about it, maybe that's just it.

Comment: cehck the docs for the eventObject http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ you can see the values and the methods you can call on it, you could use a browser inspector to watch the e object to understand it better

Comment: Yep, just ran across this as well. Your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!